# UEFI BIOS Utility Boot order

Tags: linux, boot

I have changed boot order on my Asus desktop(UEFI BIOS).SanDisk USB is #1,still it does not boot from USB.Why?
Should I change Compatibility Support Module?
Where to read more about this?
My boot order
[image]

I have created my USB with rufus,with GPT Partition Schema for UEFI.

Comment: 1. You have EFI firmware (which despite its name is not a BIOS). EFI boots from a file on a EFI system partition. As such the device you intend to boot from must have sucha partition and a bootloader on it.  2. CSM stands for Compatability shims. If enables part of the old functionality of a BIOS. If it is enabled you can boot from devices with a legacy bootsector.  3.  CSM will be dropped int he future, so trying to go EFI only atm is best.   4.  Sometimes you need to insert the USB pendrive **before** booting in order for some EFI firmware to find them.

Comment: I have inserted USB pendrive that is not a problem.I am trying to understand what is wrong with my settings.

Comment: Are you sure that whatever is on the USB drive is UEFI-bootable? Does a file `\EFI\boot\bootx64.efi` exist? Is it formatted using FAT32?